# Opera Mini & PHP Sessions

Tags: php, session, cookies, opera

I have tried passing sensitive information from 1 page to the next using Cookies and PHP Sessions but still no luck.  This works fine in all browsers I have tested except Opera Mini. I also found this: http://caniuse.com/#search=cookie

This is how I have it currently setup.

**page1.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
$time = time();
$key = '';
$hash = md5($key . $time);
$_SESSION['inno'] = '';
header("Location: page2.php". $hash);
exit;
?>
```

**page2.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset( $_SESSION['inno'])) {
include("../global/header.php");
include("../global/content.php");
}
session_destroy();
?>
```

The content of the page is the sensitive information, So that is why it goes from page1.php to page2.php.

Is there some kind of workaround for this if passing information this way isn't supported in Opera Mini?

Comment: I for one don't really understand your question, You say you're having problems passing information using sessions, but you haven't provided any examples where you are actually doing anything with data...

Comment: Cookies are supported in all major browsers, but they might be disabled. The link you posted is about local storage, which is something different. Your code doesn't seem to do much, but I assume this is an incomplete sample. If it works in other browsers, it's probably a problem in storing the cookies in Opera Mini, maybe because they are disabled, or due to some other issue. Still, if you want us to judge if your code should work, please make a complete example that actually uses data and with which you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe this could help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10981509/2191572

Comment: @JonStirling I think OP made a very simplistic representation of their code and merely forgot to add `$_SESSION['var_name'] = 'some data';` somewhere

Comment: `...don't process cookies sent in anything but a 2xx response - you are responding with a 302 redirect...` from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2584379/2191572 seems relevant

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Not that it changes the fact that it's not there, mistake or not ;)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That's a nice collection of relevant links. I didn't know about cookies vs 2xx, but it's likely to be the issue.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I did come across the first link and thats the same issue I am having. the other browsers in my stats have visitors while Opera Mini has 0 starting from the day I began using `session_start();`.  The 2nd link looks like an interesting option but I'm not sure how to implement.  Would I have to switch completely from PHP sessions or is there a way to implement this only for opera mini?

Comment: I am not sure where your issue is occurring. Could you try the following? (1) remove or comment these two lines: `header("Location: page2.php". $hash); exit;` from `page1.php` (2) visit `page1.php` in your browser (3) visit `page2.php` in your browser.

Comment: By doing this, `page1.php` will be producing a 200 response to the web browser and in theory the session should stick. If the session is not sticking then there is something else going on.

Comment: Also, there are several different ways to initiate a redirect without the use of PHP's `header('location:');` but it requires client-side compliance

Answer (score 0):

Use classes for reusable resources, they are less messy.

Looks like you forgot to assign data, so

Here is the promising structure:

**index.php**

```
<?php

include_once 'session.php';

$my_session = new session_helper;

//SET YOUR SESSION VARIABLES

if($my_session->get_session_data('username') == null){
    $sessionData = array(
        'username'=>'me',
        'logged'=>true,
        'password'=>md5('password')
    );
    $my_session->set_session_data($sessionData);
}

?>
<a href="view_session.php">View my session</a>
```

**view_session.php**

```
<?php 

include_once 'session.php';

$my_session = new session_helper; 

?>

<!--GET YOUR SESSION VARIABLES-->

<p>Username: <?php echo $my_session->get_session_data('username'); ?></p>
<p>Logged: <?php echo $my_session->get_session_data('logged'); ?></p>
<p>Password: <?php echo $my_session->get_session_data('password'); ?></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<?php $my_session->debug_session(); ?>
```

**session.php** to get rid of headaches

```
<?php

//MANAGE YOUR SESSION

class session_helper
{

    //Start session when class instance created
    function __construct()
    {

        session_start(); 

    }

    //Session data set using an array to easily add multiple values e.g. on login page
    function set_session_data($sessionData)
    {

        forEach($sessionData as $key => $value){//Go through each key

            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;//And assign it to session

        }

    }

    function get_session_data($session_data_key)
    {

        return $_SESSION[$session_data_key];//Call this to get your values

    }

    function debug_session()
    {

        print_r($_SESSION); //Check what session contains if something is wrong

    }

    function close_session()
    {

        session_destroy(); //Good to use for fresh start/logout.

    }

}

?>
```

- session.php manages sessions. Accessing directly will output an empty page.
- index.php uses a condition to set the variables. You don't need to rework data everytime when you have it.
- view_session.php has all the info regarding the session.
- Best practice of retrieving info is storing secure/encrypted primary keys of the database, then use them to retrieve everything else from the database, e.g. by user ID get the e-mail, profile creation time, name, surname etc.